# How to update sql table counter field numbers to be inverted?

Tags: sql

I have a table with two item items and a counter. I want to update the counter field so that the counter field numbers are inverted. For example, it changes from small to large from large to small.

| id | item | no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 3 | a | 2 |
| 4 | b | 2 |

After the update

| id | item | no |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 2 |
| 2 | b | 2 |
| 3 | a | 1 |
| 4 | b | 1 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: thanks I found the answer select * into tbl1 from ( SELECT id, item, row_number() over (partition by item order by no desc) as no FROM tbl)a

Comment: thanks I found the answer select * into tbl1 from ( SELECT id, item, row_number() over (partition by item order by no desc) as no FROM tbl)a

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to return a result set with the "inversion", use `row_number()`:

```
select id, item,
       row_number() over (partition by item order by no desc) as new_no
from t;
```

Comment: thanks I found the answer  select * into tbl1 from
(

SELECT      id, item, row_number() over (partition by item order by no desc) as  no

FROM     tbl)a

Answer (score 1):

If I go like this:

```
with aux (id, item, no) as(
    select 1, 'a', 1 from dual union all
    select 2, 'b', 1 from dual union all
    select 3, 'a', 1 from dual union all
    select 4, 'b', 1 from dual)
SELECT
    id,
    item,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY item
        ORDER BY
            id ASC
    ) no
FROM
    aux
ORDER BY
    id;
```

My output is:

```
id  item no
-----------
1   a   1
2   b   1
3   a   2
4   b   2
```

However, if I do this:

```
with aux (id, item, no) as(
    select 1, 'a', 1 from dual union all
    select 2, 'b', 1 from dual union all
    select 3, 'a', 1 from dual union all
    select 4, 'b', 1 from dual)
SELECT
    id,
    item,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY item
        ORDER BY
            id DESC
    ) no
FROM
    aux
ORDER BY
    id;
```

My output is:

```
id  item no
-----------
1   a   2
2   b   2
3   a   1
4   b   1
```